# How do I break apart 电子纸是利用电泳显示技术原理发明而成的?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I'm struggling to understand how the part in bold breaks apart:

> **电子纸是利用电泳显示技术原理发明而成的**，之所以也被称为“纸”，是因为它可以最大限度地模拟传统纸张的功能。
> <sub>[HSK6 past exam](https://sirichina.jp/learning/7283/2/); also [Coursera HSK6 course, week 7, lesson 3](https://www.coursera.org/learn/chinese-for-hsk-6/lecture/2jwW7/zhi-shi-yu-ji-neng-di-33ke)</sub>

Breaking it apart literally...

> Electronic paper [电子纸] is [是...的] utilizes [利用] electrophoretic display technology [电泳显示技术] principle [原理] invention [发明] manufactured from [而成].

I'm finding it hard to put these pieces together.  It seems it just means "electronic paper has an electrophoretic display" with some buzzwords added in: "electronic paper utilizes the invention of the principle of electrophoretic display technology for manufacturing."

**Question**: How do I break apart 电子纸是利用电泳显示技术原理发明而成的?

Answer (score 2):

电子纸 - Electronic paper

是 - is

利用 - using

电泳显示技术原理 - the principles of electrophoretic display technology

发明 - to invent

而成的(产品) - into (product)

Replace 发明 with 创造 would make it sound more natural

> 电子纸 | 是  | 利用  | 电泳显示技术原理  | 创造 |  而成的(产品)

> Electronic paper is (a product) created by using the principles of electrophoretic display technology

Comment: I prefer 发明 to 创造 in this case.   发明电子纸 Vs.  创造电子纸.  发明电子纸 is more common.

Comment: If it has to be 发明, then my sentence would be 电子纸是利用电泳显示技术原理发明出來的

Answer (score 1):

> 电子纸是利用电泳显示技术原理发明而成的.

The main part is 电子纸*是*发明而成*的*.  You can consider it as 是...的... structure here. 利用电泳显示技术原理 answers how 电子纸 is invented(发明).  The breakdown:

> 电子纸/是利用电泳显示技术原理/发明而成的。

Answer (score 1):

电子纸是利用电泳显示技术原理发明而成的.

主语: (电子)纸

谓语: 是

宾语(从句): 利用电泳显示技术原理发明而成的.

宾语中: 利用(电泳显示技术的)原理, 发明而成的.

Answer (score 1):

I would analyze the sentence like this.

```
             电子纸   是     利用    电泳显示技术原理    发明   而  成     的
Level 1:  \-Subject-/\-------------------Predicate--------------------/
Level 2:             \P/   \-----------Direct-Object------------/    的
Level 3:                   \-----------Predicate----------------/
Level 4:                   \-------Predicate-----------/   C \Pr/
Level 5:                   \------Subject-------/   \Pr/     \-P/
Level 6:                   \-----Predicate------/   \-P/
Level 7:                   \-P/    \---Object---/

P: Predicator
Pr: Predicate
C: Conjunction
```

So if we rebuild the context from bottom up:

- E-paper is something.
- E-paper is the product of something. (I liberally chose the word "product" for 成. 成 really means become/turn into)
- E-paper is the product of some invention.
- E-paper is the product of an invention utilizing something.
- E-paper is the product of an invention utilizing the Electrophoretic Display principle.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the sentence is correct.

技术 and 原理 took the same position. You can say either 电泳显示技术 or 电泳原理, but not 技术原理。Either tech or theory but not both.

Also 是利用～发明的 is also a little weird to me. The order is correct but twisted. More straightforward version should be 电子纸的发明利用了～.

而成 should be combined with 制作 instead of 发明, because you can say 制作成～的样子 but not 发明成～的样子。

The correct sentence should be

- 电子纸是利用电泳原理发明的
- 电子纸的发明利用了电泳原理
- 电子纸是利用电泳显示技术发明的
- 电子纸的发明利用了电泳显示技术
- 电子纸是用现代生产工艺制造而成的